# how to properly sleep in loop

Tags: java, timer, blocking

I have a loop who's job is to act as a blocking command,  execute a shell command once every second. Java warns about "sleeping in loop".  Here is the code:

```
    while (!Shell.silentShellCommand(stringCommand).contains("Device detected")) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log.errorHandler(ex);
        }
    }
```

Surely there is a better way to do this.  I just don't know how.  What would be the proper way to make a "blocking timer method"?   I am using this to pause execution until the user does something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
public void loopMethod(){
    if(!Shell.silentShellCommand(stringCommand).contains("Device detected")){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        loopMethod();
    }
}
```

And just call that method from a background thread. Would that work? I mean, it's still technically a loop, but it looks cleaner for some reason!

Comment: I did something simlar which was to have my loop call a sleepForOneSecond();

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute something every second, there is a better way:

First create a timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Then schedule a fixed time execution:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Your repeatable execution here
  }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

That's it. Hope I could help.

Comment: timer won't work.  I am working in a separate thread and I need this thread blocked. timer would be good to instantiate a new thread, but not block the original.

Comment: You can add a cyclic relationship. Inside Timer's execution, you can callback your main Thread to wake it up. Something like that. If it doesn't work, try to use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)`. Don't know if it is exactly what you want, but take a look at this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html

Answer (score 0):

The classic variant is to use `wait()`
// waiting thread

```
synchronized (mutex) {
     wait();
}
```

// other thread notifies when the waiter should wake up

```
synchronized (mutex) {
     notify();
}
```

If your task is to execute a code at regular intervals, then you would use `TimerTask`
Example see answer of Giovanni

Comment: ah, so I create a new thread dedicated to waiting around, and the original thread just waits for the new thread?    Sounds simple enough and will get rid of the little yellow warning... I just don't understand why I have to go around my elbow to get to my wrist in this case.